# XPath 1.0 - Selecting Text at Different Node Depths

Tags: xpath

I am posting here in hopes of having an expert weigh in on how best to combine text values from different node depths and with a text value being indexed.

I am trying to figure out how a single XPath 1.0 statement can be created from the following two statements.  The text values are located at different depths and with the second statement having an indexed text value.

The two paths I would like to combine are as follows:

```
div/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]/a/text()
div/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]/text()[2]
```

The context in which this resides is where a comment poster has provided their name as either an anchor (from which to contact) or is just plain text.

The text selected in the first statement comes from anchors that do not have any nested text.  The text selected in the second statement requires an index as neighboring or nested text exist and thus must be explicitly provided.

Any advice or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Michael

**EDIT/FOLLOWUP**

The below excerpt shows a trimmed down version of the HTML (just tags) but leaving in a class value for a specific div.  The XPath values provided in the original question correspond to XPath queries being made from the `li` items below:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <ol>
            <li>
              <div>
                <div class="comment-author vcard">
                  <a>candaceerin</a>
                  <div class="commentmetadata">...</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>
                <div class="comment-author vcard">
                  <img/> Rachel
                  <div class="commentmetadata">...</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example snippet of both config to make it more visual for all? Depending on the pattern, `div/div[...]//text()` might  do the trick

Comment: Thanks Robin, I am evaluating a web site for extracting content for a client.  The web page is: [link](http://mybrownbaby.com/2014/01/the-problem-with-parenting-from-your-own-pain/), specifically the comments at the bottom.  When looking at the user/poster names, some names are hyperlinks (e.g., candaceerin) while others are not (e.g., Rachel).  The website is presenting user/poster names as either hyperlinks or text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [union operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-UnionExpr) `|` to combine them into one XPath statement:

```
div/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]/a/text() |
 div/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]/text()[2]
```

The following XPath expressions might also work, but they are ugly:

Option 1:

```
div/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]//text()
  [(parent::div and position()=2) or parent::a[parent::div]]
```

Option 2:

```
div/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]//text()
  [
   (parent::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]/parent::div 
    and position()=2 ) 
   or parent::a[div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' comment-author ')]/parent::div]
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you Mads as option 1 worked for my case.  Even though it might be ugly, it works for my case in a repeatable and consistent manner.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should really *edit* your answer to show the *relevant* part of the HTML instead of just linking to a full page in the comments. You're already familiar with the strucutre, whereas  it takes time and effort for us to go there and try to see what you're talking about. Also, your question as-is isn't really useful for someone else who might have the same problem.

Anyway, this XPath should catch what you want:

> //div[contains(@class, 'comment-author')]//text()[normalize-space() and not(ancestor::div[@class="commentmetadata"])]

`//div[contains(@class, 'comment-author')]` selects the div with the comment, then you try to catch *all* the text with `//text()`. After that you need to check the text string isn't empty with `normalize-space()` and the string isn't the date of the comment, which is given in a `<div class="commentmetadata"">`.